# How to plot histograms of two different classes in a single plot?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have two draw histogram of two clases in to single plot. One class is of distance of authenticated users and others if of distance of intruduers achieved by L2-NORM.

intruder_dist =[0.02, 0.05,0.03......] and another is its corresponding number. intruder_num = [10,2,40,..........]

Same is with authencticated users distances.
intruder_dist =[0,0.002,0.001......] and another is its corresponding number. intruder_num = [30,50,70,..........]
Below is the histogram that I want to achieve. How to plot it in matlab.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need `hold on` between the two calls to `histogram`/ `hist`. Here's an example:

```
histogram(10+2*randn(1,1e4), 21)
hold on
histogram(2+.3*randn(1,1e4), 11)
```

[image]

Comment: I think what he meant was to plot the bins overlayed, for that you need to loop through bins, draw the highest class first and the smallest second with `hold on`

Comment: @Marouen My example code would also work with overlaid plots; change 10 to 5 to see it

Comment: @Luis Mendo  the graph i attached in original post is of 160 images. then how its max peak is going till 900? and for importers till 600. This is confusing.

Comment: @sidraalem We can't really know without seeing the code and data

Comment: @LuisMendo I tried it out. And after running I understand the reason. Thank you for your help.